# What version of TLS does Cloud-Code Parse.Cloud.httpRequest() support?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am receiving an error when trying to connect to my server's API from CloudCode.  error:  “Request failed; 35-111 SSL connect error; Connection refused"   The server is configured to only support TLS1.2 and I am unable to verify if Parse.Cloud.httpRequest() supports TLS1.2.  It would also be helpful to know what SHA encryption algorithms are supported.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @DaNLtR We did, but I am afraid it is not applicable anymore since it had to do with how Facebook was upgrading TLS on their servers at the time.  If you are running into this issue today, then you should investigate how SSL and TLS is configured on your server.   If you pick a hosting service like Heroku, you should not have to configure TLS yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to encryption algorithms, [Parse recently migrated to the SHA-2 standard](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-parse-apps-to-the-more-secure-sha-2-industry-standard/).

The error could be caused if you are using a non-standard port for SSL connections on your server (standard is port 443).

My guess would be that TLS 1.2 is supported, but hopefully you can get confirmation on [your post at the Parse Developers Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/PUKBGgHZUlU) assuming that the issue isn't from using a non-standard port.